# haproxy logs in a container

Tags: logging, haproxy, kubernetes, containers

I’m struggling to get access and health check logs from haproxy when I run it inside a container, so I’ve followed the instructions in the docs (Setting up logs using Docker | HAProxy Enterprise 2.2r1) and my config looks like:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    daemon
    log stdout format raw local0
    maxconn     4000
    nbproc 1
    nbthread 12
    # turn on stats unix socket
    # stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
      timeout connect         10s
      timeout check           10s
      timeout client          60s
     timeout server          60s
     timeout queue           60s
     timeout http-keep-alive 10s
     maxconn                 3000
    log global
    retries                 3
frontend http_in
    mode    http
    timeout http-request    10s
   option http-keep-alive
   option forwardfor
   bind 192.16.1.103:80
   use_backend http_be

backend http_be
   mode    http
   option http-keep-alive
   option forwardfor
   option redispatch
   balance roundrobin
   server 192.16.1.6 192.16.1.6:80
   server 192.16.1.5 192.16.1.5:
```

80

But the only logs I sees in the kubernetes logs are then haproxy starts:

```
kubectl logs vcn1-lb1-78c4c86676-w4q2p
Proxy http_in started.
Proxy http_be started.
```

I’ve tried:

```
log stdout format raw local0 debug
log stderr format raw local0 debug
log stderr format raw local0
```

But nothing gives me access or health check log data? The type of log I want, is the type you see when not running haproxy in a container:

The type of log I'm looking for are the standard logs you get when you run it outside a container:

```
Jan 23 10:29:00 ca-rain03 haproxy[5789]: Health check for server admin_be/ca-rain03 succeeded, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, check duration: 1ms, status: 3/3 UP. 
Jan 23 10:30:52 ca-rain03 haproxy[5789]: 253.255.0.35:44932 [23/Jan/2021:10:30:52.270] http_in admin_be/ca-rain01 0/0/0/1/1 200 219 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

As for the suggestion to listen on port 1024, nothing is listening on that port either in the container or on the pod node:

```
netstat -ntpl 
   Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name 
   tcp 0 0 192.16.1.103:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 12/haproxy 
   tcp 0 0 192.16.1.103:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 12/haproxy
```

Or outside on pod node:

```
netstat -ntpl | grep :1024 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:10248 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 21586/kubelet 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:10249 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN – Br
```

Comment: Talking from the perspective of community edition `HAProxy Ingress Controller` you can get the stats like `healthz` on the container port 1024 (web browser should be better to display all of the tables rather than `curl`). Please check what this port is exposing and tell if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please don't put code snippets in the comments, as they're very hard to read; [edit your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1051127/edit) and include them there. Plus, you can fix your "I've tried" stanza to be formatted correctly, too; win-win :-)

Comment: done pas per reques